# Set layout_centerVertical to a TableLayout from code

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm creating a new TableLayout inside my onCreate() method on the Activity.java. I've researched the several methods to modify the properties of a Layout but I haven't found anything :(

Further explaining what I mean: When you place a view or layout inside a RelativeLayout, you can set two parameters: layout_centerVertical and layout_centerHorizontal. Setting these two attributes to true will place the layout in the middle of the screen.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert view inside TableRow you can specify layout_gravity and gravity. Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html